# Using cURL within Github Action causes infinite step process

Tags: curl, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I'm not quite sure how best to explain the issue I am seeing, but essentially I am just making a simple cURL request.

The particular Github action step is as:

```json
      - name: Perseus API cURL Test Stack on http
        run: |
          curl --silent --show-error --fail -v -L http://0.0.0.0:8001/
```

So, in effect, the curl request is supposed to silently fail or show an error if there are any issues.

However, all I see is a continuously processing step, and the pipeline never finishes or exits from this step:

[image: Perseus API cURL Test Stack on http]

However, there are no issues with the API at that endpoint locally when the stack is running:

[image: Local cURL Command Works]

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to what is going wrong here?

For verbosity mode, I get the following in the Github action:

[image: Perseus API cURL Test Stack on http Verbose]

Comment: Hmmmm, it seems that if I perform the cURL directly after the `docker compose up -d` command, it works.